# Bug ao editar pergunta com tag organização-de-projeto

Tags: bug, tags

Hoje fui editar uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285637) que fiz no StackOverflow e guando fui salvar a pergunta deu erro porque ao editar a tag `organização-de-projeto` vira `organiza&#231;&#227;o-de-projeto`, os acentos se transformam nos respectivos códigos em ISO-8859-1, se não me engano, porém esse bug só ocorre no celular.

Não testei mas pode ser que o problema esteja em todas as tags acentuadas.

Comment: não tinha achado essa pergunta no meta

Comment: Eu uso o app da StackExchange. Não ocorre esse erro e é mais bonito de interagir do que a versão mobile do site. Tem versão Android e iOS